# Why does this javascript function keep returning an array as undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, return, undefined

I have this simple function "decode" that takes in 2 arrays as input, where the second array is used to decode the first array.

The starting input (not when the function recurses) must always be of the following format:

1. 1st array is of length 1
2. 2nd array is of a length that is a power of
       2, minus 1 (1,3,7,15,...)

Example input:
`([4],[0,2,6])`

For some reason, my code always returns undefined when I try to return a decoded array. In fact, I can't seem to return anything other than undefined, even when I change the return statement to something like "return false". The log statements show that the correct values are being captured for both arrays, leaving me very confused.

Here's my code:

```
var decode = function(A, B){
    console.log("A: "+A+" B:"+B);
    console.log(B.length);
    if(B.length===0){
        return A;
    }
    var newA = [];
    var newB = [];
    var act = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<A.length; i++){
        newA[act] = A[i] - (B[i]/2);
        newA[act+1] = A[i] + (B[i]/2);
        act+=2;
        newB = B.slice(i+1);
    }
    decode(newA, newB);
}

console.log("Answer is" + decode([4], [0,2,6]));
```

This will always return undefined, regardless of what you make the return statement. Console.log(A); on the other hand is giving me the correct value for what I want to return.

Thank you very much for the help! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: because there is no 'return' keyword in the function.

Comment: @dwjohnston there is one... always returning `A`... But indeed some sort of `return` is needed close to the end... making this post simple "typographical error".

Comment: Just `return decode(newA, newB)`

Comment: @smnbbrv Thanks! This gave me what I wanted. However, I still don't understand why this worked and not what I did... I'm a little confused maybe about recursion/return statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if B.length != 0, there is no return value. 
Change

```html
decode(newA, newB);
```

to

```html
return decode(newA, newB);
```